# How to access a web server installed on Hyper-V

Tags: apache, ubuntu, hyper-v

I have installed Ubuntu on Windows 8 using Hyper V.  Having also installed Apache 2 I had the notion that I was going to use this as a web dev environment.  I set up an external switch so that my ubuntu installation could access the internet.  So far everything was progressing swimmingly.  The problem I am encountering is that I have no idea how to access the web server from my machine.  I can get the IP address that ubuntu picks up and type that into my browser whereupon I am informed "It works!".  That's all good but I move around among several networks and I should not have to look up the IP address every time, and that can't facilitate having multiple sites installed.  I just want to be able to enter something like

```
"http://mytestserver/"
```

into my browser to access it.

Any pointers on how to set this up properly would be much appreciated.

Comment: How you set up networking will be based on how your Ubuntu machine is connected to the Net. Bridged or NAT are your options. Let us know the details around the VM's network connection and we can help. Basically your going to need a static IP, nameserver entry and DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

I have always had the most success with Bridged networking in VM Guests and would definitley recommend you go with that option. What you then could do and what I have done is to assign a static IP for the server and assign the hostname as below. You will have to know what IP addressing is available or you can use 192.168.1.x if your inside your network.

The easiest way would be to assign a static IP in /etc/network/interfaces replacing the 0.0.0.0 with the correct entries for your network

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 0.0.0.0.0
 netmask 0.0.0.0.0
 gateway 0.0.0.0.0
 broadcast 0.0.0.0.0
 dns-nameservers 0.0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0.0
```

and then edit your /etc/hosts file and add that static IP and add the Hostname mytestserver. You will already have the localhost entry and possibly others. Just make sure you assign the Static IP address you assigned in interfaces to mytestserver. You may also have to make this same entry in your machines hosts file simply because it will not have a DNS record.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
0.0.0.0 mytestserver
```